# Spring - How do I run a series of threads and wait for them to finish before finishing?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot, asynchronous

Currently I have this code, I would like to use  built in Spring functionality. I am using @Async for a method I do not care about when it finishes. Is there a way to use that but wait until those threads in the pool finish?

```
   Runnable thread = () -> {
                for (String date : dates) {

                    Path dir = Paths.get(primaryDisk, partition, folder, date);
                            File tmp = dir.toFile();
                            deleteDir(tmp);



                }
            };

            executor.submit(thread);
```

and later in the function I use the following code to wait for them to finish.

```
 executor.shutdown();

            try {
                executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use spring you can use something like this

```
public void doSomething(Set<String> emails){
        CompletableFuture.allOf(emails.stream()
                .map(email -> yourService.doAsync(email)
                        .exceptionally(e -> {
                            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            return null;
                        })
                        .thenAccept(longResult -> /*do something with result if needed */))
                .toArray(CompletableFuture<?>[]::new))
            .join();
    }
```

This code will start every doAsync method call in other thread and will wait for all this tasks to finish.

Your doAsync method

```
@Async
public CompletableFuture<Long> doAsync(String email){
    //do something
    Long result = ...
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(result);
}
```

If your doSomething method and doAsync method are in same service class you should selfinject your service

```
@Autowired
@Lazy
private YourService yourService
```

and call your @Async method through this selfinjected reference(spring proxy)

```
yourService.doAsync(email)
```

to run it realy asynchronously.

Comment: Could you explain the @Lazy and why I had to Autowire my service inside of itself? Also the .toArray part? Thanks! it worked as I needed it to.

Comment: @Dylan '@Lazy' means spring will inject it when it needed and not on statrtup. Selfinject is a circular dependency without it sometimes you'll get exception on startup. A lot of spring "magic" is done by proxies https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/23/transactions-caching-and-aop-understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring so mostly all injected bean are not original beans but proxied by spring. This proxy handles '@Async' and does all work with executor behind the scene. To use this "magic" you need to call methods through this proxies. Direct call(same class method) doesn't use spring proxy = no "magic".

Comment: @Dylan .toArray part is like we get an array of CompletableFuture with java 8 stream api. This array is passed to CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture... cfs) method and than .joined() is called to wait all this array of jobs to finish. More about CompletableFuture https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/

Comment: @JaneXQ I have tried this code but it seems that it is not starting threads async.. It is doing it sequentially. Any idea how to fix this